# Смена изображения при выделении

Tags: cocoa, objective-c, ios

Как в UITableView изменять изображение на ячейке при выделении (в режиме non-editing), если используется стандартный тип ячеек?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не собирал, но уверен что должно отработать верно

```
- (NSIndexPath*)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView 
 willSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"img.jpg"];
    return nil;
}
```

P.S. этот метод нужно определить в классе-делегате

Answer (score -1):

Есть способ поставить разные картинки в эти поля:

```
cell.imageView.image = defaultItemImage;
cell.selectedImage = selectedItemImage;
```

Comment: selectedImage устаревшее свойство...